# Firestore new async setData method doesn't throw server error

Tags: swift, firebase, generics, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue with one of Firestore methods `setData`, this method doesn't throw server errors!

As you can see in my custom `addDocument` method down below, the function I use inside it `setData` should be simple and marked with a `try` but the issue that this method also has a completion that returns an optional `error` from server which I don't know how to handle it in an `async throws` context

Check my comments inline inside the code

````swift
// I can use this simple line 
try documentReference.setData(from: data.self)

// But the above don't throw the error after the server respond!
// I need to use the below but son't know how?
try documentReference.setData(from: data.self) { error in
    // Here I want to throw the error after server respond back for any error
}


```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class DatabaseProvider: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = DatabaseProvider()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    private init() {
        
    }
}

// MARK: Document related methods such add, update, get and delete operations
extension DatabaseProvider {
    
    /// Generic function to write data
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - collection: The database collection that you want to save this document into
    ///   - documentId: Optional to provide document id if nil, an auto-generated document id will be given
    ///   - data: The object that you want to add to collection
    ///
    func addDocument<T: Codable>(
        to collection: Collections,
        documentId: String? = nil,
        with data: T
    ) async throws {
        let collectionReference = db.collection(collection.name)
        var documentReference = collectionReference.document()
        if let documentId = documentId {
            documentReference = collectionReference.document(documentId)
        }
        
        // I can use this simple line 
        try documentReference.setData(from: data.self)

        // But the above don't throw the error after the server respond!
        // I need to use the below but son't know how?
        try documentReference.setData(from: data.self) { error in
            // Here I want to throw the error after server respond back for any error
        }
    }
    
}
````

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I created a `private` method to handle all errors in old way using `completions` and then in my original method I used the new [withCheckedThrowingContinuation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedthrowingcontinuation(function:_:)) function and inferred it with `(continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) -> Void` to convert it to `async throws` way

Here is my code, feel free to use it and if you have any suggestions please share it here

```swift
//
//  DatabaseProvider.swift
//
//  Created by Abdullah Alhaider on 10/06/2022.
//

import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Helper4Swift

typealias DB = DatabaseProvider

class DatabaseProvider: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = DatabaseProvider()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    private init() {
        
    }
}

// MARK: Document related methods such add, update, get and delete operations
extension DatabaseProvider {
    
    /// Generic function to write data
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - collection: The database collection that you want to save this document into
    ///   - documentId: Optional to provide document id if nil, an auto-generated document id will be given
    ///   - data: The object that you want to add to collection
    ///
    func addDocument<T: Codable>(
        to collection: Collections,
        documentId: String? = nil,
        with data: T
    ) async throws {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) -> Void in
            addDocument(to: collection, documentId: documentId, with: data) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                } else {
                    continuation.resume()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addDocument<T: Codable>(
        to collection: Collections,
        documentId: String? = nil,
        with data: T,
        completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void
    ) {
        let collectionReference = db.collection(collection.name)
        var documentReference = collectionReference.document()
        if let documentId = documentId {
            documentReference = collectionReference.document(documentId)
        }
        do {
            try documentReference.setData(from: data.self, merge: true, completion: completion)
        } catch {
            completion(error)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    /// Gets the document from a given collection and id
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - collection: The database collection that you want to save this docement into
    ///   - documentId: The document id to fetch
    ///   - source: Source of data
    ///   - type: The output of this data
    ///
    /// - Returns: The retrieved document object
    func getDocument<T: Decodable>(
        from collection: Collections,
        documentId: String,
        source: FirestoreSource = .default,
        as type: T.Type
    ) async throws -> T {
        let collectionReference = db.collection(collection.name)
        let documentReference = collectionReference.document(documentId)
        return try await documentReference.getDocument(source: source).data(as: type)
    }
}
```